# PivotItem header style when Pivots ItemsSource is set to datacontext MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Im applying MVVM pattern and when I created my ViewModel for the Data I set the ItemsSource of my pivot as follows:

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext}" x:Name="TripsSegmentsPivot" Title=" " Foreground="#FF888888" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

But I want my pivot items to have styled header like this

```
<PivotItem.Header>
    <TextBlock Margin="0, 16, 0, 0" Text="settings" Foreground="#FF888888" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Light"/>
</PivotItem.Header>
```

Where to set this in the xaml, or in the code-behind and if the last, where exactly in the ViewModel somehow?

This is how my Pivot xaml looks like in MainPage.xaml:

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext}" x:Name="TripsSegmentsPivot" Title=" " Foreground="#FF888888" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <PivotItem Margin="8,8,8,0">
                    <PivotItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0, 16, 0, 0" Text="{Binding S}" Foreground="#FF888888" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Light"/>
                    </PivotItem.Header>
                </PivotItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs I have

```
this.DataContext = new MyPageViewModel();

var viewModel = (MyPageViewModel)this.DataContext;

if (true == viewModel.LoadDataCommand.CanExecute(null))
{
   viewModel.LoadDataCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

but nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

V.G.,

I answered another one of your questions where the root cause of the issue was the way your XAML includes the `PivotItem` inside of the `DataTemplate`. Simply put, don't do that. :) 
This is from the same app you are building so it may fix your issue.

Take a look at my answer for [PivotItems do not resize after binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625949/pivotitems-do-not-resize-after-binding) and refactor your XAML to what I describe. If you still have the issue with the header binding, please send me a message and I will come back here and help you fix it.