# PivotItems do not resize after binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone, pivot

I am binding a PivotItems but somehow the items are not resized properly, according to my margin declaration. Why is that?

**EDIT: here is my new code and it still has gaps..**

```
    <Pivot x:Name="TpsSegmentsPivot" Title="Locator" Foreground="#FF888888" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TpTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Margin="0, 16, 0, 0" Foreground="#FF888888" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Light"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    </Pivot>
```

*This is the template:*

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TpTemplate">
    <ListBox Background="Black"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Seg}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionUCTemplate}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is a screenshot with the red pivotItem..

[image]

Comment: On the screenshot you can see that the red pivot item is not with margin "8,8,8,0".. Why is this?

Comment: Please provide the full XAML for this page. Something outside of the code you provided must be going on.

Comment: Specifically, what `Margin` is set in the `StaticResource` called `PivotStyle1`?

Comment: <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with the extra space is the Piviot Item you are using inside the DataTemplate tag. remove it and bind the header to a header template. I've used data binding on Pivots before and never seen this issue.

From one of my released apps:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="CAMPING CHECKLIST" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCategories}" Name="MainPivot">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Your pivot item content here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

I believe the PivotItem in a PivotItem is the root of your issue.

your code should look similar to:

```
<controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding tripTypeViewModel.TripTypeViewModelDataSource}" x:Name="TripsSegmentsPivot" Title=" " Foreground="#FF888888" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.tripTypeViewModel.HeaderText, ElementName=TripsSegmentsPivot}" Margin="0, 16, 0, 0" Foreground="#FF888888" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Light"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox x:Name="ItemsLB" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.tripTypeViewModel.Segment, ElementName=TripsSegmentsPivot}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:SectionUC HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

The first image is how I describe it, the second is how you currently have it :

[image: mine]
[image: yours]

Answer (score -1):

This is the standard behaviour for PivotItems since they are always displayed with a margin. You should set a negative margin:

```
margin="-20,0,-20,0"
```

Comment: I am not sure this is an appropriate solution. What does standard behaviour mean? A bug in the framework?

Comment: I've built a few apps with pivots and this is what I always did. You can google this question and you will hardly find a better solution than setting a negative margin. I don't think it's a bug. It's just that the pivot always has a margin.

Comment: Clear! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ill open that post again, because there is something that bugs me. What does PivotItems "standard behaviour" means, when If i add them programatically from the code-behind everything is fine, but when I use Data Binding to a viewModel it isnt?

Comment: While this may make the issue visually disappear, it doesn't actually address the root cause. Please refer to my answer. The margin shouldn't be an issue if everything is properly nested.

Comment: I think i nested everything ok in the updated code, but there seems to be the same problem